# How to output variables from two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

Given the following schema:

```
desc teachers; 
| Field     | Type 
+-----------+-------------- 
| id        | int 
| name      | varchar 
| school_id | int 
| age       | int 

desc schools; 
| Field     | Type 
+-----------+-------------- 
| id        | int 
| name      | varchar
```

Output a list of all teacher names and the name of the school they teach?

I tried..

```
SELECT Name.Teachers, Name.School
JOIN Schools S ON School.ID = S.ID
FROM Teachers T
```

Output the difference in age between each teacher and the next oldest teacher at each school?

Comment: I have answered your first question but need more clarification on second question.

Comment: Your query is missing a `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Teachers' name with their school names

select t.name, s.name from teachers t inner join schools s
on t.scho_id =s.id

Answer (score 0):

The first part would be solved like this

> SELECT t.name, s.name FROM schools AS s INNER JOIN teachers AS t ON s.id =
> t.school_id

the second part is not well explained..

Comment: What exactly are you asking??